# Как конвертировать c++ builder в си.

Tags: c++builder, c, c++

Здравствуйте!

Есть код. http://ideone.com/HC5EeV
Меня не интересует его визуализация, а интересен алгоритм. Я, к сожалению, не знаю c++ builder. Есть ли инструмент, которые автоматом перепишет его на Си или хотя бы c++.

Спасибо.

Comment: Может кто знает как c++ в c конвертировать?

Comment: Не думаю, что есть автоматическая тулза. Если проект маленький, попробуйте вручную. Не забывайте, что программа могла быть написана не по стандарту, и не работать на современном компиляторе, даже если вы сможете это откомпилировать.

Comment: Посмотрел на код. Если вы уберёте всё, связанное с отображением (`TForm1`, `Graphics` и т. д.), останутся чистые вычисления, которые по идее не зависят от компилятора. Код написан отвратительно, вычисления вперемешку с отображением, поэтому легко не будет. Но ничего реально сложного.

Comment: @VladD, то есть я могу безболезнено все билдерские функции убрать? А с с++ на си я и сам смогу загуглить и переписать код.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК: По идее, да, почти все они нужны лишь для реакции на события и рисования. Вам, однако, придётся разобраться в логике этого кода, чтобы случайно не выкинуть нужный кусок. (Функции рисования на `Canvas`'е тоже что-то подсчитывают.)